# Problem with DiscretizeRegion

Tags: bugs, regions

**Bug fixed in 10.1.0**

---

```
R = RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], Disk[{1/2, 0}, 1/2]] // 
  RegionDifference[#, RegionUnion[Disk[{1/2, 0}, 1/6], Disk[{-1/2, 0}, 1/2]]] &
(dr = DiscretizeRegion[R]) // Timing
```

If you run this codes in many times, you will find that it will give a result in 1 second with 50% probability,while it will not give a result in 100s with 50% probability.

win7 v10.0.2

Perhaps it is related to the performance of computer. The better the computer performance,the greater probability it gives a result in 1 second. If we run this codes in [Wolfram Programming Cloud](http://www.wolframcloud.com/), it always give a result in 1 second.

Comment: Please do not use the bugs tag until the issue has been confirmed as a bug by WRI or the _Mathematica_.SE community.

Comment: What do you mean by "Sometimes"? Why do you think it should always finish the computation in less than 100 seconds?

Comment: @m_goldberg If you run this codes in many times, you will find that it will give a result in 1 second with 50% probability,while it will not give a result in 100s with 50% probability.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, though it happens much less frequently here (OS X, M10.0.2).  You should report it to Wolfram.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, also on Windows 7 V10.0.2. Seems like a bug, but I'll let others decide on that.

Comment: In my case, it's more like approximately 65% chance of executing in 0.12 seconds, 30% chance of taking a very long time, and 5% chance of crashing the kernel instantly.

Comment: I can reproduce this as well on Win8.1 MMA 10.0.2

Comment: I can reproduce it in V10.0.2, Mac OSX 10.10.2. Not surprisingly it also happens with `Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; ToElementMesh[R]`.  It does not happen with the option `Method -> "RegionPlot"`, but the cusp is truncated.

Comment: Seems fixed in current development code.

Comment: I do not understand what is the bug here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [**user21**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21) in the comments, this bug has been fixed as of version 10.1.0.

```
Table[(RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], Disk[{1/2, 0}, 1/2]] // 
         RegionDifference[#,RegionUnion[Disk[{1/2, 0}, 1/6], Disk[{-1/2, 0}, 1/2]]] &) //  
           DiscretizeRegion // AbsoluteTiming // First, {100}] // Mean       

(* 0.142127 *)
```