# MeshRegion and BoundaryMeshRegion differences between 10.0.1 and 10.0.2

Tags: regions

**Original text**

My need is simple:
I have many non-overlapping regions that I will need to use as plotting domains and integration domains. The new region type operations in Mathematica 10 has made my life so much easier until 10.0.2 came out. When I first started with regions I asked 
the following question: [RegionUnion issues with many Regions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65289/regionunion-issues-with-many-regions) which was if I'm using `RegionUnion[]` on many regions the CPU would run full tilt until the kernel quit. The answer was to simply use `DiscretizeRegion[]` on my regions before I used `RegionUnion[]`. This worked very well so I wrapped it up deep in one of my packages and went on to my real work.  I have since upgraded to version 10.0.2 but now my package will not work.

Here is a simple function to make a region with a flag to return either the region as is or to apply  `DiscretizeRegion[]` first:

```
 r1[x_, ds_, r_: 1] := If[ds,
  DiscretizeRegion@Disk[{x, 0}, r],
  Disk[{x, 0}, r]
  ]
```

Lets use it to do some simple operations with two flags to easily try the different cases.

```
 d = 2.1;
 ds = False;
 OuterDS = False;
 If[OuterDS,
  DR = DiscretizeRegion,
  DR = Identity
 ];
R = RegionDifference[
       DR@RegionUnion[r1[0, ds], r1[d, ds]],
       DR@r1[d/2, ds, .5]
   ]
 Area[R]
 Head[R]
 Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] R]
```

If I use `ds=False`  and `OuterDS = False` everything works and I can use `R` in my integration. But I then quickly run into my old problem of the kernel crashing when there are lots of regions. If I use `ds=True` then it no longer works with either value for `OuterDS`. Remember I'm using 10.0.2 and this did work on 10.0 and I think it also worked on 10.0.1. I also tried this on the Mathematica online where it works for all cases!

It comes down to the following difference between versions. When I use `RegionUnion[]` on a list of `DiscretizeRegion[]` I get an object with the head `BoundaryMeshRegion` when I used to get `MeshRegion`. I cannot use `RegionDifference[]` on a `BoundaryMeshRegion` and a `MeshRegion` using 10.0.2 but this does work on the Mathematica online.

Is there a way to force region operations on `MeshRegion` to return a `MeshRegion` and not a `BoundaryMeshRegion`? Has anyone else run into this problem? If you have 10.0.1 can you try this code and tell me if it works for you?

**Edit 1**
I may close this. I have tried testing on another computer also with 10.0.2 and everything works. I then tried my real code and package and now it works?! But what was causing the problems in my simple code below? Some how with kernel history I got to a point where I could not use `RegionUnion[]` on `BoundaryMeshRegion` and a `MeshRegion`. So if you read this take it with a bit of 
skepticism. If I find out I was doing something stupid I'll remove this if I find a subtle order of events that caused this odd behavior I'll edit to point it out.

**Edit 2**
This is bad. I can now run the same code and get different results. I even use the `Quit[]` and re-evaluate in the same order and I seem to randomly get different results!?

What I get when it does not work:
[image: Dose not work]

What I get when it does work:
[image]

**Edit 3**
I have taken my full package and have run it on 10.0.1 with no problem. However, I have not found small clean example that shows the difference between 10.0.2 and 10.0.1 yet.

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion` [appears to be bugged.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73470/121)  This could easily be related.

Comment: I'd suggest to send that in to the tech support for someone to look at.